# Makefile Error 2 when installing GODDeSS package in Ubuntu VMware

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, vmware

I am pretty new to Linux and I am installing the GODDeSS package, an extension to GEANT4 in VMware Ubuntu 20.04.
Instructions I follow are in [this](https://git.rwth-aachen.de/3pia/forge/goddess-package/-/wikis/Installation_and_Usage). After I compile and try to install using `make -j2 install` I get the error:

`/home/simulation/goddess/source/G4BasicObjects/G4PropertyFileReadInTools/src/Properties.cc:72:6: **error: no declaration matches ‘void Properties::parseTabular(std::ifstream*, std::string)’**
   72 | void Properties::parseTabular(std::ifstream* in, std::string key) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/simulation/goddess/source/G4BasicObjects/G4PropertyFileReadInTools/src/Properties.cc:9:
/home/simulation/goddess/source/G4BasicObjects/G4PropertiesFileReadInTools/include/Properties.hh:62:7: note: candidate is: ‘void Properties::parseTabular(std::ifstream&, std::string)’
   62 |  void parseTabular(std::ifstream& in, std::string key);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/simulation/goddess/source/G4BasicObjects/G4PropertiesFileReadInTools/include/Properties.hh:24:7: note: ‘class Properties’ defined here
   24 | class Properties {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/simulation/goddess/source/G4BasicObjects/G4PropertyFileReadInTools/src/Properties.cc: In member function ‘bool Properties::load(std::string)’:
/home/simulation/goddess/source/G4BasicObjects/G4PropertyFileReadInTools/src/Properties.cc:191:17: **error: cannot convert ‘std::ifstream*’ {aka ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>*’} to ‘std::ifstream&’ {aka ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>&’}**
  191 |    parseTabular(&in, result[1]);
      |                 ^~~
      |                 |
      |                 std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}`

It hit one google hit which suggested python compatibility for which I upgraded to python 3.8.2 however it didn't solve any issues. How would I solve this error?

EDIT 1: Included the errors.

Comment: `-j2` makes installation parallel, which might not work. Try `make install`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems to be that you didn't copy the most informative part from the Makefile output. Most probably somewhere earlier there was a reference to the actual error. Also to find it certainly makes sense to run without  parallelization, as Jens proposed

Comment: @Jens Hi, I tried `make install` it ran into a different error, which I have updated in question. It seems to refer to C++ header files.

Comment: @zgyarmati Hi, Thank you! I have edited the question and included the actual error.